# Replace all instances of a character in a String

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that replace all instances of a certain character in a word with a new character. This is what I have so far:

```
public class practice {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test3 = updatePartialword("----", "test", 't');
    System.out.println(test3); }


public static String updatePartialword(String partial, String secret, char c) {
    String newPartial = "";
    int len = secret.length();
    for (int i=0; i<=secret.length()-1; i++){
        char x = secret.charAt(i);
        if (c==x) {
            String first = partial.substring(0,i);
            String second = partial.substring(i+1,len);
            newPartial = first+x+second;
        }


    }
        return newPartial;
}

}
```

I want it to return t--t, but it will only print the last t. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Java already has a built in method in String for this. You can use the the [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method to replace all occurrences of the given character in the String with the another character

```
    String str = "Hello";
    str.replace('l', '-'); //Returns He--o
    str.replace('H', '-'); //Returns -ello
```

Comment: Why `replaceAll`? Do you need regex syntax here? If not use `replace` instead (it also replaces all occurrences).

Comment: @Pshemo Oops, my bad. Hahah forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test3 = updatePartialword("----", "test", 't');
    System.out.println(test3);
}

public static String updatePartialword(String partial, String secret, char c) {
    char[] tmp = partial.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++) {
        char x = secret.charAt(i);
        if (c == x) {
            tmp[i] = c;
        }

    }
    return new String(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you overwrite the String each time you found the character. Instead of overwriting, you should expand the string each time.

```
public class practice {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test3 = updatePartialword("----", "test", 't');
    System.out.println(test3); 
}

public static String updatePartialword(String partial, String secret, char c) {
    StringBuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
    sb.append(""); // to prevent the Stringbuilder from calculating with the chars
    for (int i = 0; i < partial.lenght; i++)
      if (secret.charAt(i) == c)
        sb.append(c);
      else
        sb.append('-');
    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```